# Trying to print JSON value

Tags: python, json

I have JSON output from the dell website and I'm trying to access the values but really having a hard time accessing the values.

For example, I have the following JSON being retrieved:

```
    {   
    "GetAssetWarrantyResponse": {
        "GetAssetWarrantyResult": {
            "Faults": null,
            "Response": {
                "DellAsset": {
                    "MachineDescription": "T350, New Balance",
                    "ShipDate": "2010-05-04",
                    "ServiceTag": "89M1",
                    "OrderNumber": 518,
                    "LocalChannel": 25,
                    "AssetParts": {
                        "@nil": "true"
                    },
                    "CountryLookupCode": 11,
                    "ItemClassCode": "V02",
                    "IsDuplicate": "false",
                    "ParentServiceTag": {
                        "@nil": "true"
                    },
                    "CustomerNumber": 1121,
                    "Warranties": {
                        "Warranty": [
                            {   
                                "StartDate": "2011-05-05",
                                "EndDate": "2013-05-04",
                                "ServiceProvider": "U",
                                "ServiceLevelCode": "D",
                                "ItemNumber": "992-82",
                                "EntitlementType": "EXTENDED",
                                "ServiceLevelDescription": "Next Business Day Support",
                                "ServiceLevelGroup": 5
                            },
                            {   
                                "StartDate": "2010-05-04",
                                "EndDate": "2011-05-04",
                                "ServiceProvider": "U",
                                "ServiceLevelCode": "N",
                                "ItemNumber": "993-0",
                                "EntitlementType": "INITIAL",
                                "ServiceLevelDescription": "Next Business Day Support",
                                "ServiceLevelGroup": 5
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So for example, if I wanted to retrieve the value of "ServiceTag" how would I go about getting that in python? For some reason when I try to do things like:

```
raw_data = urllib2.urlopen('https://json.url')
djson = raw_data.read()
djdata = (json.dumps(json.loads(djson), indent=4))
print djdata['GetAssetWarrantyResponse']['GetAssetWarrantyResult']['Faults']['Response']['DellAsset'][0]['ServiceTag']
```

I'm getting:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./warranty.py", line 35, in <module>
    print djdata['GetAssetWarrantyResponse']['GetAssetWarrantyResult']['Faults']['Response']['DellAsset'][0]['ServiceTag']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: Are you coming from a XML background ? I'm not sure where all those `a:` prefixes come from but more importantly, I don't get how it does not raise a `KeyError` with the structure you showed us.

*In short, please post more actual code and a minimal sample that we can execute to reproduce the problem. As it stands, this question lacks too much information.*

Comment: have you looked at json library https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: Why are you calling `json.dumps`?  That transforms a python dict into a JSON string, which seems like the opposite of what you want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `json.loads` to create a python dict containing the JSON information.

Then, access it just like any python dict.

```
import json

mydict = json.loads(json_response)

print mydict['GetAssetWarrantyResponse']['GetAssetWarrantyResult']['Response']['DellAsset']['ServiceTag']
```

Comment: Why do I have the feeling that giving the OP a copy-pastable answer won't really help him to solve such problems in the future ? (That being said, it's a good answer)